# Call a function when button is clicked in a different window (WPF app)

Tags: c#, wpf

I launch a window from a page of my wpf app and I would like to call a function when a button is pressed in the child window

**Here is the page that calls the window :**

```
namespace AppWpf10
{
    public partial class Prepare : System.Windows.Controls.Page
    {
        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Choice win2 = new Choice();
            win2.Show();
        }

        public void DoStuff()
        {
            //CODE THAT DOES STUFF
        }
    }
}
```

**The window launched :**

```
namespace appWpf10
{
    public partial class Choice : Window
    {
        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

So I would like `DoStuff()`to be called upon `button1` being pressed in the other window. How should I do it ? By calling `DoStuff()` in `button1_Click` from the child window ? Or by adding an event "button1 pressed in the other window" ?

Either way, anyone knows how to write it ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are many ways and by the looks of it, you're not going the MVVM route, which is fine.  So, in your particular situation, a simple way is to subscribe to the child's button click event when you actually create the child, given that you named the button:

```
namespace AppWpf10
{
    public partial class Prepare : System.Windows.Controls.Page
    {
        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Choice win2 = new Choice();
            win2.Show();
            win2.button1.Click += clickEventHandler;
        }

        private void clickEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DoStuff();
        }

        public void DoStuff()
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to give parent to child window in constructor and then it can call its parent methods:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Choice win2 = new Choice(this);
    win2.Show();
}


public partial class Choice : Window
{
    Prepare parent;

    public Choice(Prepare parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        parent.DoStuff();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I got this error regarding the `parent.DoStuff();` line "'System.NullReferenceException' exception :Object isn't defined to one instance of an object" (poor translation)

Comment: I got it working using B.K.'s answer, but still, big thanks to you.

Comment: I cannot tell why that error occurs. Show us more code - how you create new window etc.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me.
I have generated event for show popup which popup control is putting in another (**MainWindow**) window page and I am rendering from **FooterPanel** which is my **UserControl** in WPF.

```
foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
{
     if (window.GetType() == typeof(MainWindow))
     {
         (window as MainWindow).MyPopup.IsOpen = true;
     }
}
```

You can also refer the link which has another way to doing it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/events/how-to-add-an-event-handler-using-code?view=netdesktop-6.0